# Jacuzzi tub faucet removal

Tags: faucet, bathtub, removal

[image]I am trying to replace a deck mounted faucet on a jacuzzi style bath tub. There is no access to underneath. I removed handles and top trim but this appears to me be impossible without breaking marble surround and getting access to underneath.

Comment: You're going to need to be underneath it to reattach the next faucet anyway. Mine was installed [& maintained] from the floor below, through the ceiling, because you still can't reach the taps or waste with the surround removed.

Comment: @Ecnerwal the answer being "yes you need to bust (or at least remove) some tile?" :)

Comment: ... or access it from below. Fairly common to access tub plumbing from the floor below unless they are on the lowest floor.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no access panel, is the side with the faucet next to an interior wall?  If so you can cut a hole there that will be easier to repair. if that answer is no, then opening the deck is the only answer.